# REST architectural style concepts

Tags: rest

I'm new to the concept of REST. And so far I've used a REST client (Advanced REST client) to make all the requests. But I don't understand the point of it all if I have to use a REST client to access the web service. I mean how then is a layman supposed to access a web service in his browser? And can browsers at all access access web services? If yes then why do  I need a REST client?

Comment: REST isn't really for "laymen accessing from a browser".  It's for sharing data between programmers, either in your own application or with a developer of another application.  You don't need any sort of official REST client, anything that can communicate over HTTP and parse XML will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layman access a REST service all the time, when they access a web site (though many web sites violate REST principles to varying degrees). The REST architectural style was arrived at by examining why HTTP worked well, and was then used the conclusions to influence how HTTP 1.1 improved on 1.0.

They aren't expected to access a REST **web-service**, because a web-service is a service which uses the properties used by websites to provide machine-readable rather than human-readable data. A RESTful web-service tries to do this by taking advantages of how HTTP works and working with that. (The earliest "web services" seemingly started with the assumption that the web was a failure and needed to be coerced into working with the sort of RPC model that had been used previously, despite the fact that if this was true there'd be no advantage in using the web rather than the existing RPC protocols).

The layman therefore would more likely use an application that in turn used web services (whether that application was a web application, desktop, mobile, or whatever). The layman uses them the same way that they use any programming techniques; they use something devs built using them.

> And can browsers at all access access web services?

Often they can get at least read-only access and sometimes a bit more. When this is the case it can be extremely useful for debugging.

Comment: So it would be correct to say that a web browser can access a web service albeit indirectly.

Comment: They can directly access them, but they mostly show a bunch of XML or JSON or similar that isn't much use to most end users. I did once build one that had XSLT meaning the exact same service also served as a site, but that was as much to see if I could as something generally useful.